# Reading Images with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having trouble reading an image with OpenCV.

```
Exception has occurred: error
OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ttbyx0jz\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:404: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
  File "C:\opencv\summer project\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    cv.imshow('Cat' , image)
```

Here is my actual code:

```
import cv2 as cv

#reading images
image = cv.imread('C:opencv\summer project\cat.jpg')

cv.imshow('Cat' , image)

cv.waitKey(0)][1]
```

Comment: Not sure about this, but wouldn't you just need to remove the `as cv` and keep it `import cv` and replace all of the `cv`'s with `cv2`. Cannot see what else would be wrong about this. Also, was it a mistake that you inputted the `]` in the end of `cv.waitKey(0)]`?

Comment: The cv.waitKey(0)] was a typo or something

Comment: Please, stop adding answers to this. Problems caused by typos are off-topic, and there's no value in adding more incomplete explanations of how string literals work in Python.

Comment: I know I'm not an expert with OpenCV and debugging, so please be more empathetic

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have a problem with the image path.

Possible solutions:

- use raw string literals: `r'C:\opencv\summer project\cat.jpg'` or `'C:\\opencv\\summer project\\cat.jpg'`
- or use `os.path` (good practice): `os.path.join('C:\opencv\summer project', 'cat.jpg')`

Make sure your path is correct.

Comment: The argument to `os.path.join` still needs to be either raw string literal, or have the backslashes escaped. This just works by accident -- have the directory names start with a,b,f,n,r,x ... and it won't.

Comment: OK @DanMašek, you are right, thanks. I think `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('__file__')), 'cat.jpg')` should work instead.

Comment: @R.Marolahy it would be `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'cat.jpg')` actually